# How to reset PC without reverting back to factory OS, Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, reset

My notebook comes along with Windows 8 which is factory default OS. I upgraded that Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 via Store. After a long time of usage, I want to reset my Windows as the files were stored for too long and many are starting to become corrupted. I know resetting the Windows 8.1 will revert me back to factory default OS, Windows 8. As the internet connection from my country is too slow, I don't want to give time to upgrade it again. I want to reset without losing the Windows 8.1.

Appreciate every answers and comments. :)

Comment: Sounds like you need to take routine full OS system image backups and learn the entire process. Otherwise perhaps a reset while keeping settings, etc. may be something to research for Win 8.

Comment: Well, I tested  with Recovery USB which is created by Windows 8.1. Even recovering with that USB reverts back to Windows 8. I just don't want to waste time and bandwidth by downloading the same updates again and again.

Comment: Resetting the OS from Window 8.1 Recovery Environment also reverts back to 8. I think I have no options left :(